# Get value data-colonne using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have n AJAX request and I need to get the value of `data-colonne` to send to my controller.

```
<th class="text-left">
    <span>
        <?php echo $colonne; ?>  
        <span  data-colonne="<?php echo $v; ?>" class="fa fa-chevron-down status-red" ></span>
</th>
```

```html
$.ajax({
    url: "/sortindex"
    data: {Value on my data-colonne},
    type: 'post',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('ok');
    }
});
```

`<?php echo $v; ?>` = It's the id on the colonne

I have my controller and my request ajax my route. I need just to get the value on `data-colonne` in my span

Thanks a lot

Comment: can you show the full code. what do you have so far?

Comment: What event is the AJAX request fired under? How does that element relate to the `span` with the data attribute you're trying to find?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the values of data attributes with jquery using

```
$('.text-left > span').attr('data-colonne');
```

Jquery also has a `.data()` method, which stores the values internally and doesn't add an attribute to the dom

[.attr docs](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

[.data docs](http://api.jquery.com/data/)